# Change Property of control type with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a web page with 5 grids and 1 button. I want to program the page to allow the user to click a button and have the text size on the 5 grids be changed. How might I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

The following is one implementation of what it might look like to have a single button that cycles through some predetermined fontsizes for a particular region on the page:

```
// Our fontsizes, and cached selectors
var fontsizes = ['10px', '16px', '20px', '30px'],
    $buttonEl = $("#modify"),
    $affected = $("#affected"),
    index;

// When our button is clicked
$buttonEl.on("click", function () {
    // Determine new font-size for the affected region
    $affected.css("font-size", function (index, size) {
       // Get index of current size in our array
       index = $.inArray(size, fontsizes);
       // Return the next font size in the list (wraps)
       return fontsizes[++index % fontsizes.length];
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MLVAJ/1/